# PHPMailer is failing on Travis builds

Tags: php, phpmailer, travis-ci

i have been working on php7 upgrade and also moved phpmailer to be loaded via composer.

we have a build system that is tested on Travis. we use grunt to run selenium tests.
when i test locally (`grunt test`) all tests pass, but when i push to Travis (via GitHub) there are some tests that are failing.

tests that fail return following message (in Travis log after setting SMTPDebug to 3):

> 2018-06-27 12:39:23 Connection: opening to smtp.sendgrid.net:587, timeout=300, options=array()
>   2018-06-27 12:43:37 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to smtp.sendgrid.net:587 (Connection timed out) [/var/www/includes/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php line 325]
>   2018-06-27 12:43:37 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
>   SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

strange thing is that there are some passing tests that use the same code as failing tests. we instantiate our wrapper object with the same attributes in each of the scripts that are sending mail.

this is the except from the code that is failing to send mail:

```
$mail->sendMsg($config->getOpt('site_name'),
               $config->getOpt('site_email'),
               $userInfo['userName'],
               $userInfo['userEmail'],
               Strings::strPad(_('Purchase confirmation from'),1,' ',STR_PAD_RIGHT) . $config->getOpt('site_name'),
               $boostPurchaseConfirmMsg,
               nl2br($boostPurchaseConfirmMsg));
```

this is the except from the the code that is sending mail:

```
$mail->sendMsg($config->getOpt('site_name'),
               $config->getOpt('site_email'),
               $_POST['userEmail'],
               $_POST['userEmail'],
               Strings::strPad(_('Welcome to')) . $config->getOpt('site_name') . '!',
               $registerMsg,
               nl2br($registerMsg));
```

this is the function within our wrapper object that is actually sending mails:

```
public function sendMsg($fromName, $fromEmail, $toName, $toEmail, $subject, $messageText, $messageHTML = null, $CCs = null)
{

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    if (false === $mail) {
        throw new gException('No PHPMailer object available');
    }
    try {
        $mail->isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
        $mail->Host = $this->host; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->Port = $this->port;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = $this->username; // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = $this->password; // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

        $mail->From = $fromEmail;

        $mail->FromName = $fromName;

        $mail->addAddress($toEmail, $toName); // Add a recipient
        $mail->addReplyTo($fromEmail, $fromName);

        if (null !== $CCs) {
            if (is_array($CCs)) {
                foreach ($CCs AS $cc) {
                    $mail->addBCC($cc);
                }
            } else {
                $mail->addBCC($CCs);
            }
        }

        $mail->WordWrap = 50;
        $mail->isHTML(true);

        if (strlen($messageText) < 1) {
            $messageText = $messageHTML;
        }

        if (strlen($messageHTML) < 1) {
            $messageHTML = $messageText;
        }

        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body = nl2br($messageHTML);
        $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($messageText);

        return $mail->send();
    } catch (PHPMailerException $e) {
        throw new gException('PHPMailer exception message : ' . $e->errorMessage());
    }
}
```

**please help**. i have already tried setting mock smtp service on Travis, but it doesn't matter. i reviewed if we are using correct port. i did all the things that phpmailer wiki suggest to try troubleshooting.

i repeat tests are passing locally, so everything is working. Travis is holding me hostage.

## UPDATE

this might seem misleading, the solution, as it turns out, was to not check PHPMailer success on sending mails. we had the agreement that we will not inform the user that mails are not sent, since they are only informative, instead we will be logging exceptions for further analysis.

**do not test mail success on travis**, it will fail. travis doesn't allow outbound SMTP traffic.

use the strategies proposed by the PHPMailer troubleshooting wiki.

thank you @Syncro

Comment: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#FTP-SMTP-other-protocol-does-not-work

Comment: been there, done that. some scripts are sending mails as they should, but some are failing. i have been searching and retesting in the past five days, relentlessly.

Comment: I would fully expect a public CI system to block outbound SMTP by default- this is why the PHPMailer test suite doesn’t do it, but fires up a local mock SMTP server. OTOH, it may be that Travis provides an alternative, such as a local mail server, which might explain why you are receiving some messages.

Comment: @Synchro what is even stranger, all these tests passed while we were on php5 and PHPMailer was downloaded by hand (i think we were using the latest version for the php5). i agree with SMTP blocking, but it should be uniform form all tests, not selective as it is now.

Comment: Travis CI is not uniform. Each of their config has its idiosyncrasies. To be sure, test it - include a shell script that tries to telnet to your mail server.

Comment: i will try. thanks.

Comment: @Synchro i added this to my test spec and got `Connection timed out (110)` again.  
this is the script i ran  
    >$fp = fsockopen('tls://smtp.sendgrid.net', 587, $errno, $errstr, 60);
    >if (!$fp) {
    >    echo "$errstr ($errno)\n";
    >} else {
    >    $out = "QUIT\r\n";
    >    fwrite($fp, $out);
    >    while (!feof($fp)) {
    >        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    >    }
    >    fclose($fp);
    >}

Comment: Right, so it looks like outbound connections to port 587 are blocked, which isn't too surprising - though you've written a PHP script not a shell script, so if you're being blocked by PHP config rather than network config, you can't tell, which is why I suggested a shell script.

Comment: @Synchro this is the output from travis (i added a line in before_script section of .travis.yml)

```
$ echo "quit" | telnet smtp.sendgrid.net 587
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
Trying 167.89.123.53...
Trying 108.168.183.160...
```

Comment: Ok, so now you know it’s blocked in the network, so there’s nothing you can do from PHP.

Comment: thanks. this is not helpful at all, since it doesn't deal with original issue.
some tests that send mails are passing travis builds (not raising any errors), but others are failing. we haven't found a reason why the tests are failing, despite being same as the ones that are passing.
i can confirm that we are actually sending mails, even though test fails. our test account is receiving mails.
thanks again.

Comment: it turned out that the tests that were passing didn't check for success output.